# JSF 2.2 ViewScoped Bean gets created multiple times

Tags: jsf-2

I am using JSF 2.2.

When I use ui:repeat in a nested composite component, (The composite componenet is child of an other composite component) my ViewScoped Bean gets created on every request. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Which JSF 2.2 impl/version? Mojarra is currently at 2.2.2, have you tried it? 2.2.0 and 2.2.1 have too many problems.

Comment: @BalusC It is 2.2.0 I will try 2.2.2 and report. But I could break it down, that it definitely is the ui:repeat in the child composite component.

Comment: The new `xmlns.jcp.org` namespace caused many problems in 2.2.0/2.2.1, particularly in composites and HTML-rendering. Another way to exclude this from being the cause is to rename `xmlns.jcp.org` back to `java.sun.com` and retest. If it solves that, then upgrading to 2.2.2 definitely solves your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It definitely was a Problem with 2.2.0 and composite components. We re now in 2.2.4 and it works fine.